# Pinia Components not updating after changes to state Vue3

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vue-component, pinia

I have 2 dropdowns (one is dependent on the other). My code for the component is supposed to preload a list of databases from an api call and then subsequently on selection of database get a list of collections associated with that database via an api call. The UI is making the correct calls, but for some reason my components are not reactively updating on changes to the pinia store. I can see the updates to the store in  Vue development tools, but component fails to update correctly on changes or on initial load.  Fiddling with the code seems to load sporadically.

Here is my component definition:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light navbar-bg">
    <a class="sidebar-toggle d-flex">
        <i class="hamburger align-self-center"></i>
    </a>

    <form class="d-none d-sm-inline-block">   
        <div class="input-group input-group-navbar">
            Select Database:
            <Dropdown v-model="selectedDatabase" :options="databases.databases" 
            optionLabel="name" 
            placeholder="Select a Database" 
            class="w-full md:w-14rem" 
            @change="updateSelectedDatabase()"/>
        </div>
        <div class="d-none d-sm-inline-block">
            Select Collection            
            <Dropdown v-model="selectedCollection" :options="collections.collections" 
            optionLabel="name" 
            placeholder="Select a Collection" 
            class="w-full md:w-14rem" />
        </div>
    </form>

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-align">
            <li>
                <table class="p-datatable-table"><tr><td>JSON:Documents: </td><td>{{selectedDatabase.jsonCount}}</td></tr></table> 
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Here is the typescript code for the component.

```js
import { Options, Vue } from 'vue-class-component';
import {useRootStore} from "@/store/rootStore";
import Dropdown from 'primevue/dropdown';

const store = useRootStore();

@Options({
    name: 'NavbarComponent',
    components: {
        Dropdown
    },
    data: ()=>({
       selectedCollection: {},
       selectedDatabase : {},
       databases: store.databases,
       collections: store.collections,
    }),
    methods:{       
        updateSelectedDatabase() {
            store.updateSelectedDatabase(this.selectedDatabase)
        }, 
    },
    beforeCreate() {
        console.log("Fetching database")
        //This doesnt update the initial combobox
        store.fetchDatabaseList()
    },
    beforeUpdate() {
        console.log("beforeUpdate")
    }, 
})

export default class Navbar extends Vue {}
```

Here is my Pinia store definition

```js
import {defineStore} from "pinia"
import collections from "@/data/collections.json"
import analysis from "@/data/analysis.json"
import databases from "@/data/databases.json"
import {fetchDatabases,fetchCollections} from "@/api/services"
import {Databases,Collections,Analysis, NameCount,Database,AnalysisItem}  from "@/api/types"

interface RootState {
  collections : Collections,
  databases   : Databases,
  analysis    : Analysis,
  selectedDatabase : Database,
  selectedProperty : AnalysisItem,
  selectedCollection : NameCount,
  limit : number
}
export const useRootStore = defineStore("root",{
    //State
    state: ():RootState => ({ 
           collections :{collections:[]} as Collections,
           databases : {databases : []} as Databases,
           analysis : {} as Analysis,
           selectedDatabase : {} as Database,
           selectedCollection: {} as NameCount,
           selectedProperty:  {} as AnalysisItem,
           limit : 100
        }
    ),
    getters: {
      getDatabases():Databases {
        return this.databases.databases
      },
      getCollections():Collections {
        return this.collections.collections
      }
    },
    actions: {
      async fetchDatabaseList() {
          var data = await fetchDatabases();
          this.databases = data
        
      },
      async updateSelectedDatabase(database:Database) {
        this.selectedDatabase = database
        let collectionData = await fetchCollections(database)
        this.collections =  collectionData
      },
      fetchCollections() {

      },
      fetchAnalysis() {

      },
    }

})
```

I tried several ways to resolve issue, but not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: "_my components are not reactively updating on changes to the pinia store_".  what changes?  please be specific.  your code is not self documenting so it'd be nice to give others an exact use case with description of the code/logic flow, example values, and expected vs actual results.

Comment: Figured out issue. I needed to use destructured values from Pinia Store. Like the following:

import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'
const store = useRootStore();
const {databases,collections,limit} = storeToRefs(store)

 data: ()=>({
       selectedCollection: {},
       selectedDatabase : {},
       databases: databases,
       collections: collections,
       limits : [100,500,1000,10000],
       limit: limit
    }),